# Angular2 Template set class depending on tag-attribute

Tags: templates, angular

is there a way to set a class inside a tag depending on its attributes ?
Currently im building a treeview and want to set glypicon arrows depending on tree is opened or not.
I`m using bootstrap collapse so syntax is something like this

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#someElementId"><span class="glyphicon-arrow-left"></a>
```

When not expanded -tag has class="collapsed" and Attribute aria-expanded='false'

Is there a way to set the class in the span depending on its parents attributes or class with not using javascript in the scope ?

something like

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class='collapsed' href="#someElementId"><span class="[parent.class]=='collapsed'?glyphicon-arrow-left:glyphicon-arrow-down"></a>
```

???

Comment: What is the attribute that the class should depend on?

Comment: it could depend on the aria-expanded attribute for example 

<a data-toggle="collapse" class='collapsed' href="#someElementId" aria-expanded="true">

could although depend on the class

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" #parent class='collapsed' href="#someElementId">
  <span [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-arrow-left': parent.nativeElement.className=='collapsed', 'glyphicon-arrow-down': parent.nativeElement.className!='collapsed'">
    (...)
  </span>
</a>
```